# How to modify query to remove double-quotes from all columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query I run - the results of which are put into a .csv for another program to run: that other program chokes on double quotes.  So, I normally just do a quick Find & Replace in Excel replacing all double quotes with nothing.

I have a new, edge scenario though - and the output file this time is > 2,000,000 rows, which means I can't open it in Excel to do a Find & Replace.

Is there a decently straightforward way to remove double quotes from query results?  My knee-jerk reaction is to go with CASE or maybe Variables, but neither seem particularly clean to do.

I didn't post the query because it's > 100 rows, and I'm thinking there's probably a general concept here.

Thoughts?

Comment: How the data looks like?

Comment: It would be name & address fields that may have errant double quotes.  There are a lot of other columns / calculated columns as well, but only name/address should have the double-quote issue. I probably shouldn't post a screenshot due to privacy concerns.

Comment: will `replace(address, '"', '')` works for you ?

Comment: D'oh, yes I think REPLACE is the function I wasn't aware of / will work perfectly!  Do you want to put it as an answer so I can select it?

Comment: no worries. Glad it works for you

Comment: what does it got to do with single quote `'` ? The issue is with `double quote`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
  Name    VARCHAR(45),
  Address VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('"FirstName"', '"FirstAddress"');

SELECT *
FROM T;

SELECT REPLACE(Name, '"', '') Name,
       REPLACE(Address, '"', '') Address
FROM T;
```

Or better to use `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` functions as it can be `"First"Address"` for example, that ensure just the first and last one are removed

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - 1), LEN(Name) - 2) Name,
       LEFT(RIGHT(Address, LEN(Address) - 1), LEN(Address) - 2) Address
FROM T;
```

**Returns**

```
+-------------+----------------+
|    Name     |    Address     |
+-------------+----------------+
| "FirstName" | "FirstAddress" |
+-------------+----------------+


+-----------+--------------+
|   Name    |   Address    |
+-----------+--------------+
| FirstName | FirstAddress |
+-----------+--------------+
```

---

<sub>Remember **[`REPLACE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function will remove any `"` found.</sub>

Comment: I don't have write access on this database - but yes REPLACE was the function I somehow didn't know existed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the .csv file, run it through a filter.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-Content -Path '.\quotedtext.csv' |" ^
    "ForEach-Object{ $_.Replace('""','') }" >quotednot.csv
```

Comment: Did you read _Is there a decently straightforward way to remove double quotes **from query results**?_ I don't see here _From the excel file using powershell_.

Comment: Yes, I read the question. This is decent and straightforward. The query results are in the .csv file. It removes all QUOTATION MARK characters. It does not require rewriting the SQL and identifying every field that might need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh - REPLACE function would work perfectly for this.  So just for each selected field `REPLACE(FieldName,'"','')` to remove all double quotes.